# POM.xml managing nested directories and resource filtering

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm having a few issues with a pom. Basically we want to filter an entire directory, but there are portions of that directory that I don't want to filter, but still need to include in my build.

Here is an example:

folder directory:

```
some/
  path/
    dir1
      stylesheet
    dir2
      imageFile
    dir3
      fontFile
```

then in my pom I have something like:

```
<resource>
  <directory>some/path</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

This is great, except i'm running into issues with the fontFile and imageFile type files so I need to exclude them from the filtering. My first reaction would then be to do something like this:

```
<resource>
  <directory>some/path/dir1</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>    

<resource>
  <directory>some/path/dir2</directory>
  <filtering>false</filtering>
</resource>    

<resource>
  <directory>some/path/dir3</directory>
  <filtering>false</filtering>
</resource>
```

now for my actual implementation this would be extremely unscalable and a little verbose. So I was curious if there was a way to set this up so that we could set the filtering on the top level and then exclude the directories we don't want to filter.

So I'd like something like:

```
<resource>
  <directory>some/path/dir1</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/*.eot</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*.svg</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*.ttf</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*.woff</exclude>
  </excludes>
</resource>
```

how ever this stops all of my font files from being included in the target all together. I've tried a few different combinations in hopes that I could possibly include the files and then do the filtering, something like this:

```
<resource>
  <directory>some/path</directory>
  <filtering>false</filtering>
  <includes>
    <include>**/dir2/**</include>
    <include>**/dir3/**</include>
  </includes>
</resource>

<resource>
  <directory>some/path</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/dir2/**</exclude>
    <exclude>**/dir3/**</exclude>
  </excludes>
</resource>
```

I'm currently at a loss, so I'm hoping someone might have some insight on how to do this without having to target each directory individually.

thank you,
Brodie

Answer (score 4):

So after doing more digging and just looking at different pom.xml files from around I found a simple way to exclude certain filetypes from a filter.

Basically when declaring the maven-resources-plugin you can set a property that will allow for all files of a type to be excluded from filtering.

my example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>eot</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>svg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

There is an alternative to this, if you don't want to exclude globally. It's very similar to what i was attempting to do in my 2nd example, but my example was a bit backwards. A better sample can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html at the bottom of the page.

form maven.apache.org

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```